# Mingw64 bit - what to do with this

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I've downloaded source files for [mingw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/).

Could someone please tell me what steps shall I make to build it on Windows7?

Comment: Since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org i suggest to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have downloaded the sources to the MinGW-w64 CRT and headers.

You want the prebuilt toolchain binaries found in:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/

There, you will find Personal builds by me (GCC 4.7 prerelease and 4.6) and sezero (GCC 4.4/4.5) in the form of zip or 7z archives you can unzip and use after adding `mingw??/bin` to your PATH.

You can also use the sometimes more updated autobuilds, but they're lacking some features.

Note there are also cross-compilers for Linux.

Comment: I'm getting (from qt) following errors when tried to use those compilers you've suggested:qtcreator_ctrlc_stub: Command line failed: C:/.../mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe
17:35:18: The process "C:\...\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" crashed.
Error while building project My_Project (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make' Would you know why?

Comment: @smallB Any way I could try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up, it works now (gcc 4.7). But I've also tried clang and this seems to not working (or I'm doing something wrong?, possibly). Anyway, when I set compiler to clang++ and then try to compile some buggy code (I want to see those improved error msgs) then I'm getting (in qt) on the command line that I've run g++ not clang++. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: @smallB: Note that GCC 4.7 is prerelease and mey not be as stable as you wish. If you generated your makefiles with qmake, you should be able to do `mingw32-make CXX=clang++` to use Clang. I recommend using the latest Clang package with the GCC 4.6.4 build, because GCC 4.7's libstdc++ is not as compatible with Clang as I'd like.

Comment: @rubenvb Can your prebuilt binaries work with other libraries?  For example, I need to support HDF5 on a Win32 target.  I'm building on OS X Lion.  How would I build/add libhdf and headers to your prebuilt ?

Comment: @rubenvb Just curious, does the compiler in these binaries support objective-c?

Comment: @AndrewB. yes. supported languages are (Obj-)C(++), Java (without libgcj), and fortran.